# Causing the data to be sorted from back to front

Tags: kotlin

Causing the data to be sorted from back to front

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val fruits = listOf("apple", "banana", "kiwifruit")
    var index = 0
    
    while(fruits.size > index){
        println("${fruits[index]}")
        index++
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your question a little bit more. What is the problem statement that you are encountering

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment (low-rep).

- use mutable list (sorting is usually modifies the collection)
- iterate via the language provided methods

https://pl.kotl.in/SC-8aXFJJ

Comment: I need to use while loop.

Comment: Then, after sorting apply your loop.

Comment: @neverdietk Why?  Other types of iteration are a little simpler, a little harder to get wrong, and a little easier to read.